# Word for "nuance" of movement

Tags: single-word-requests

I understand the word *nuance* means a very slight/subtle difference specifically applies to meanings, sounds, colours, feelings, and expressions. But what about movements, is there a word that denotes a very slight difference in somebody's movements that is not very obvious?

For example, if I'm in a room next to another room and the rooms are so silent that I could hear virtually every movement/action that the person on the other room makes, not only do I hear him walking, moving objects, him eating/drinking, writing/typing, etc., I could also hear the not so obvious/noticeable movements such as maybe him scratching his arm/leg, rubbing his eyes, to him squirming in his chair, just every subtle movements imaginable.

An example sentence maybe, *he has extraordinary trained sense organs that could detect a person's every [?] of movement. Or I could hear every [?] of movement he makes in the other room.* Is there a word that could replace *nuance* in this case to describe movements instead?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything that prohibits the use of _nuance_ to describe movement. Also, why is your use of _slight_ and _subtle_ insufficient? They complement _nuance_ quite well.

Comment: @coleopterist: yes, but 'nuance' is metaphorical for physical movements; the OP is looking for something more literal. like 'twitch', but...um... more nuanced than that.

Comment: Nuance really has more to do with a *difference in* **meaning** *as a result of the subtle difference in* the motion, sound, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider the word, [shift](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shift):

> **1** a slight change in position, direction, or tendency

Employing it in your provided sentence would render it so:

> He has extraordinarily trained sense organs that can detect a person's every **shift** in movement.<sup>*</sup>
>
> <sup>*<sub>*of* replaced with *in*.</sub></sup>

A slightly more pronounced movement could be described as a [shuffle](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shuffle).

For a non-literal alternative, consider the word, [hint](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hint):

> **1** a slight or indirect indication or suggestion:
> *he has given no hint of his views*
> **a very small trace of something:**
> *Randall smiled with a hint of mockery*

The sample sentence can be reworded to incorporate *hint*:

> He has extraordinarily trained sense organs that can detect even the *slightest hint* of a person's every movement.

Answer (score 4):

You could replace "X of movement" with [stirring](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stirring).

> **stirring** *n.*
>   A slight motion or moving about: *restless stirrings*.

Note that it does not describe an aspect of movement, but the qualitative movement itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think that perhaps "subtle (or "subtlety" for a noun) might be best applied.  It doesn't specifically imply movement, but is regularly and appropriately applied to it. (But nuance would also be appropriate in your examples.)

Answer (score 2):

how about "his senses could detect every **flicker** of movement"

I might also suggest "he could detect even the slightest **hint** of a movement"

Answer (score 1):

every **articulation** of movement

every **disposition** of movement

every **variation** of movement

every **emphasis** of movement

every **attribute** of movement

every **coherence** of movement

every **character** of movement

inflection

modulation

beat

measure...

Just ideas.  It’s an open field really; to make your nuanced point.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go with [iota](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iota):  *an infinitesimal amount*.

> I could hear every iota of movement he made in the other room.